# Get resource name of an image in android

Tags: android, image, resources, r.java-file, getresource

I need to change an image according to the image that is currently visualized. 
I know how to set an image :
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.car1);
but now I need to do the opposite. Knowing that image is in R.id.carOk I must know which drawable image is set.
Using this code 
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.carOk);
name is carOk that is not the drawable image.
How can I obtain car1?
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think from what you're saying you want to do the following:

```
Drawable myImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car1);
```

This would work from within an activity however if you're trying to do it from somewhere else then you may need to do:

```
Drawable myImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car1);
```

Comment: Thanks Dreagen but this is not what I want to do.
Inside the layout I created an ImageView with android:id="@+id/carOk".
Then inside the Activity I change the image set. If I want to know the name of the image knowing only the id of the imageview how can I do it?